# How to sync GitHub repository commits others made (local repositories)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Me and my friends made a repository for a school project. I started using visual studio code with GitHub. I can make any changes and commit it to the repository. I am using local repository because some very useful Visual Studio Code extensions don't work with remote repository.

The problem is, whenever my friend makes a change in the repository, Visual Studio Code doesn't detect it. Is there a way for me to update the changes my friend made into my folder in the repository without having to re-download the files, through Visual studio code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+workflow+two+developers

Comment: You push your changes to a common shared repository; your teammate pulls. Then he pushes and you pull. And so on.